# The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type '****'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I had previous question about my codes from here, [Error: Couldn't find constructor 'ImagePickerOptions'. ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72946680/error-couldnt-find-constructor-imagepickeroptions-imagepickeroptions-option/73007334#73007334) Now, I am facing an error regarding the setState in  the code.
My goal is to to capture image then the image will be used at the same page in the imgage asset, imgRabbitdflt1.
I followed the codes from this tutorial. [Flutter Tutorial - Image Picker From Camera & Gallery | The Right Way [2022]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xlREA-SL_k&t=339s)

I am getting this error no,

> The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'ScanScreen'. Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
> method named 'setState'.dartundefined_method

this is my code for scan_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'controller/scan_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grabbitapp/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ScanScreen extends GetWidget<ScanController> {

   File? image;

  Future pickimage() async {

    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (image == null) return;

    final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
    setState (() => this.image = imageTemporary);
    }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
            body: Container(
                width: size.width,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                        decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstant.whiteA700),
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      top: getVerticalSize(135.00),
                                      right: getHorizontalSize(10.00)),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: ColorConstant.bluegray100,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          getHorizontalSize(15.00))),
                                  child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: getHorizontalSize(5.00),
                                                top: getVerticalSize(50.00)),
                                            child: image != null ? Image.file(image!) :Image.asset(
                                                ImageConstant.imgRabbitdflt1,
                                                height: getVerticalSize(236.00),
                                                width:
                                                getHorizontalSize(320.00),
                                                fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              onTapImgCameraicon();
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00),
                                                    top: getVerticalSize(43.00),
                                                    right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00),
                                                    bottom:
                                                    getVerticalSize(27.29)),
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                    ImageConstant.imgCameraicon,
                                                    height:
                                                    getVerticalSize(77.71),
                                                    width: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        82.93),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)))
                                      ])),
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      top: getVerticalSize(135.10),
                                      right: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      bottom: getVerticalSize(20.00)),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        onTapBtnNext();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          height: getVerticalSize(40.60),
                                          width: getHorizontalSize(267.48),
                                          decoration: AppDecoration
                                              .textstylemontserratromanmedium20,
                                          child: Text("lbl_next".tr,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: AppStyle
                                                  .textstylemontserratromanmedium20
                                                  .copyWith(
                                                  fontSize: getFontSize(20),
                                                  letterSpacing: 1.20)))))
                            ]))))));
  }

  onTapImgCameraicon() async {
    await PermissionManager.askForPermission(Permission.camera);
    await PermissionManager.askForPermission(Permission.storage);
    List<String?>? imageList = [];
//TODO: Permission - use imageList for using selected images
    await FileManager().showModelSheetForImage(getImages: (value) async {
      imageList = value;
    });
  }

  onTapBtnNext() {
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.rabbitGeneratedInfoScreen);
  }
}
```

This is my scan_controller.dart

```
    import '/core/app_export.dart';
    import 'package:grabbitapp/presentation/scan_screen/models/scan_model.dart';
    
    class ScanController extends GetxController {
      Rx<ScanModel> scanModelObj = ScanModel().obs;
    
      @override
      void onReady() {
        super.onReady();
      }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class MyApp error in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597189/the-method-setstate-isnt-defined-for-the-class-myapp-error-in-flutter)

Comment: Your widget is not a statefulWidget. SetState is only available in stateful widgets

Comment: can you provide ScanController code?

Comment: @Maqsood added above.

Answer (score 0):

setState isn't defined for GetWidget. Use StatefulWidget from the material package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScanScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<ScanScreen> createState() => _ScanScreenState();
}

class _ScanScreenState extends State<ScanScreen> {

  File? image;

  Future pickImage() async {
  
    // your code

    setState(() {
      // your code
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        // the rest of your code
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have the scan controller import